# RadAsyncUpload in code behind, how to?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, telerik

My problem is, nothing happens, the code behind doesn't fire...Maybe someone could point me in the right direction. Is it possible to do something like this or am I totaly wrong here?

default.aspx:

```
    <telerik:RadProgressManager runat="server" ID="RadProgressManager1" />
    <telerik:RadAsyncUpload runat="server" ID="AsyncUpload1" />
    <telerik:RadProgressArea runat="server" ID="RadProgressArea1" />
```

default.aspx.cs:

```
    protected void AsyncUpload1_FileUploaded(object sender, FileUploadedEventArgs e)
    {
        const string relativePath = "~/Uploads/";
        var filename = e.File.FileName;
        var parentID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.SelectedValue);
        var filesize = Convert.ToInt32(e.File.ContentLength);
        var physicalSavePath = MapPath(relativePath) + filename; 

        //Store file info in database
            var app_FilesAdapter = new app_FilesTableAdapter();
            app_FilesAdapter.Insert(filename, relativePath + filename, parentID, 1, DateTime.Now, filesize);

        //Save physical file on disk
            e.File.SaveAs(physicalSavePath, true);
    }
```

Comment: Problem solved! Found the solution elsewhere, simply added the OnFileUploaded="fileUploaded" attribute to the control and then changed "AsyncUpload1_FileUploaded(object..." to "fileUploaded(object..." in code behind.

Comment: Someone asked about where I found the solution, i believe it was here: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/async-upload/radasyncupload-onfileuploaded-event-not-firing.aspx

Comment: Probably worth adding your solution as an answer and marking it to take this out of the unanswered questions list :-)